# MATLAB member function suggestion

Tags: matlab, autocomplete

If for example you have acquired a object of type handleplot with expression like below:

```
handle = plot(t,functoin1 , t , function2 ) ;
```

Now `handle` will be an array that contains two elements, `handle(1)` and `handle(2)`. Now suppose you want to change some properties of one of these objects, like set a LineWidth, change the Color, or the like.

Is there any way in which you can activate auto-completion or suggestions when you type `handle(1).` (note the memebership operator `.`)? I am looking for the automatic suggestions that MATLAB provides for member functions in a combobox near the blinking cursor, similar to the way other IDEs provide this feature:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB's objects support tab completion. After typing `handle(1).` simply hit tab and you will receive a list of available methods and properties of the graphics object.

[image]

If you want more help on a method, you will also get a popup dialog of the method and the accepted input arguments.

[image]

If you want to programmatically get a list of properties of an object, you can use `properties`

```
properties(t)
```

If you want a listing of all properties and their values, just use `get`

```
get(t)
```

Comment: it isn't provide member functions like LineWidth and like that .

Comment: @Parano Updated with a screenshot showing that it does.

Comment: i know that before i ask this question ... but as i tell previously it is not provide members like LineWidth, Color , and like that in combobox .

Comment: @Parano Look at my screenshot... it does. All properties of the object are shown in the popup

Comment: @Parano Did you refresh to look at my screenshot? Properties are shown...

Comment: yes ... but i not seeing any LineWidth and like this in the whole  combobox ... is there any indirect method for doing so ...

Comment: refresh the imgur page i provide you a snapshot of matlab documentation that uses this property .

Comment: @Parano It is not clear at all what you want. Why don't you just type `handle(1).LineWidth = 2`

Comment: i'm just wondering is there any way to do so ... tnx by the way for you patients .

Comment: if i continue to writing handle(1).LineWidth and press tab it's says that no completion found ... but as you know already there is a completion (or property which name LineWidth . my problem is raise here ....

Answer (score 0):

i use this method ... 
for example i'm writing a program in matlab editor and when im want to know the properties of an object just stop coding and  run the program , know it's have my object (for example handle) and know i can write the `properties(handle)` in command window to know the exact properties of handle . as Suever says .